# Pocket Tens vs Pocket Jacks

Tags: texas-hold-em

hi so I was playing a 1/2 NLH 9 players and I had pocket 10's last one to act ! (I had about 190 or less and he had close 800 and was running good all game)

UTG +2 raised to 15 and it was folded around to the me where I  called and 2 people were in the pot ! Flop came all 6's and he bumped it too 30 and I re-popped it to 70 and he put me all in  which I called and he had pocket Jacks. I was just wondering if I could of got away from the hand and what did I do wrong ?

Comment: That's a tough spot. I'm not sure that I can really help with an answer to this one, so I'll wait and see what others right. I think that A LOT of this is going to be player dependent - is he a really good player or just running well? Have they been bluffing? Etc, etc. Bottom line, those UTG+2 ranges can be so wide that it puts you in a rough spot

Comment: Thanks for the reply and yeah he was a good player who was running well! He didn't bluff much either! A previous hand with him I had 10s again and he had ace jack clubs and flop came all spades king high and he put me in a position to shove I had about 150 total and I folded so yeah !

Comment: If a player running well isn't really a reason to take a peek if he's bluffing. In fact, good players can take advantage of their good run, trying to sell a loose image, then catch someone. That player raised from late EP, still EP. That alone _can include a high pair_ and probably a higher one. He raised  x8 BB, too big to play. This spot asks for a HUD. Personally i would fold my humble `TT` without history and stats. With continuing aggression by him and stats like `50/35` i probably would raise him all-in preflop since the odds to double-up are far good.

Comment: @vlzvl I'm not buying that one. Our hero still had TT - you're only dead to such few combinations. UTG+2 is (usually) a pretty wide range, including for tight players. On a combinatorial basis alone, the call he made does make sense - you probably beat more of his range than not. Just on a rough basis, it's obvious what you're dead to. But then you're still alive to things like 77+ (which is easily in UTG+2 range) you're way ahead to all suited connectors, including suited broadways, you're way ahead to AKs. There's just too many hands you're still alive against to let it go.

Comment: @Jim Beam, actually what bothers me its the aggression on the flop on that bingo _666_ flop from a possibly good player (as OP said). I don't think suited connectors would dare to all-in against a short stack, who may know he's already ahead with his `TT` on that 666 `flop`. I agree you may be against `77,88,99,AK,AQ` but as well `JJ,QQ,KK,AA` but it's foggy exactly what.

Comment: I think you'd have to be seriously deep-stacked to get away from this one. Like, say, you each had 500+. You might have gotten a bit more info from a pre-flop raise, but with only 150 it probably would have gone in on the flop anyway.

Answer (score 2):

So here is my attempt at putting together an answer for this question because I think it's fascinating. This is one of those items that you may just have to go with the math on it. The first screen is the range I've chosen for our villan - it's basically the top 10% of hands, which I think is reasonable for UTG+2. It's possible that the range should be ***wider*** than what I've done since most people have a VPIP of 20% or higher and always open for a raise (in other words, it could have been coincidental that he was UTG+2). But we'll use 10% for now because I think this is pretty reasonable in this spot.

[image]

The next screen is our hero with his TT acting last, post-flop

[image]

***This puts us at 63% equity against that range.*** Obviously, it could be higher, but that's not a bad place to be. The mitigating circumstance in this is the re-raise shove post flop. Does that narrow his range down further? Maybe. But that's being somewhat results-oriented and we should avoid that. As long as the pre-flop range makes sense, then it's hard to abandon 63% equity. The opponent could have easily had a smaller pair, AK, AQs, etc, etc.

Comment: the open-raise you put is reasonable for `UTG+2`, especially for a possibly loose player and that kind of deep stack. Although, many of that hands does not compute on the flop all-in, like say _KJs_. On pokerstove on reasonable _all-in_ hands `(77+,AKs,AKo)` the equity reduces to coin-flip. Worth it? dunno. marginal situation

Answer (score 2):

I have a simpler take on this situation. TT is a good enough hand to be all in before the flop since, chances are, it is already the best hand. On this flop, the only cards that had you beat were JJ, QQ, KK, AA, or 6x. The villain probably would have bet the same with 99 or less. Sometimes the cards play themselves and you lose. Your play was correct as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 1):

That was a cash game, right? Then it would end up like that anyway. I guess reraise all-in preflop would not make much sense, he would definitely call. I think your preflop call was very correct, but what happened after that was not quite right. Actually you wanted to hit the set. It was already clear that the guy is a strong hand. As he raised quite a lot preflop, one could already assume, he didn't want to see the flop, or to have more than one player involved in this hand. So he didn't have AA, KK or even QQ. I would put him on AK, AQ, AJ or TT, but TT was in your hand. 
As the flop came you raised him, which was absolutely correct, but after he reraised you it was pretty obvious that he has a bigger pair. Ak, AQ, AJ would have been folded after your reraise. 
It was of course a bad luck that you had TT and he JJ, but honestly, I would definitely consider folding after his reraise on flop. That showed that he has a pair, and there were 4 pairs that beat you. As you said, he was not bluffing much, so in this particular case you should be folding.
If that was a tournament - easy fold, probably even preflop.

Comment: Running good doesn't mean playing tag, and the pre-flop raise could have been standard for that table at the time. I think you're making a lot of assumptions here with little or no evidence to support them.

Comment: well I was obviously not there, so I can only assume. You are also making assumption that preflop raise could have been standard. Maybe or maybe not. I'm just telling how I would evaluate this situation and to me it's obvious that such reraise after flop does mean something. Just saying...

Answer (score 0):

That is a huge open pre.  I am OK with the call.  TT is as good enough hand to call but if you 3bet and get 4bet you have lay it down.  You have enough behind to set mine if villain has a monster like AA, KK, QQ, or JJ.

Villain does not have you on AA or KK as you should have 3bet pre.  Maybe even QQ and AKs should have 3bet there.

I cannot really put either of you on A6s.

Your bet of 70 has you pot committed.  That is call, fold, or shove spot for you.

At that point villain knows he is only dead to QQ so it is a clear shove.

Villain could be doing this with AK, AQ, 99, 88 but not likely. He knows you are pot committed. It is probably not a bluff but again you are pot committed so you need to call.